# RMII to USB conversion IC

Tags: microcontroller, usb, ethernet, rmii

May I know any IC exists for converting USB Type C to [RMII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media-independent_interface#RMII). The intention is to communicate between SOM module and micro-controller.

SOM support USB type C and RMII is present in micro-controller.

Answer (score 1):

RMII is pretty networking-oriented, and on a pretty different logical level than USB.

So, I think the easiest solution might be a USB network card controller. If you find one that allows for a separate PHY that's connected via RMII, you might convince it to directly talk to the MAC in your microcontroller. It's more likely though that you will have to go the full route:

```
                   RMII         Ethernet                        USB
Microcontroller <--------> PHY <--------> USB-C connected NIC <-----> SOM
```

Many complex SOMs do have network interfaces, simplifying this to

```
                   RMII         Ethernet
Microcontroller <--------> PHY <--------> integrated NIC in SOM
```

Comment: Many MAC devices can be directly connected with RMII, without PHYs.

Comment: Jep, but I think USB MACs without integrated PHYs are rare, hence my "it's more likely though"

Comment: Some have an integrated PHY but can also be used with an alternate one.  For example: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/UNG/ApplicationNotes/ApplicationNotes/AN4754-Using-MCHP-Bridge-Controllers-with-External-Ethernet-PHYs-DS00004754.pdf

Comment: https://www.asix.com.tw/en/product/USBEthernet/High-Speed_USB_Ethernet/AX88172A "The AX88172A, USB 2.0 to MII controller, provides an optional External Media Interface (EMI) for an external PHY or an external MAC depending on different application purposes .... The EMI can also be a Reverse-MII or Reverse Reduced-MII (Reverse-RMII) for glueless MAC-to-MAC connections to any MCU with Ethernet MAC MII or RMII interface."

Comment: And another one: https://www.asix.com.tw/en/product/USBEthernet/High-Speed_USB_Ethernet/AX88772B

Comment: @BenVoigt nice!